# All in One Seo and Permalinks

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, plugin-all-in-one-seo

I'm using All in One seo and for the Post Title Format option I have it as:

%post_title% kewyord1 keyword2 etc

keyword1, keyword2 being my chosen keywords for my site

Also, in Permalinks, I have it as /%postname%/ so that the post name shows up in the shortlink/url

So with these configurations, if I make a post in with 'Books' in the title it will look like this: Books keyword1 keyword2 etc

But the shortlink, or the actual url of that post would look like this: www.mydomain.com/books

it doesnt contain the keywords I assigned in All in SEO

I tried changing the Permalink to /%post_title%/ but that didnt do anything

Anyone know how i can automatically get these keywords to show up in the shortlink automatically with having to manually do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just [change your post slug](http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/post-title-url/) to `books-keyword1-keyword2`.

[image: Edit post slug]